# Segmentation fault 11, zcat pipe into postgresql 9.0.5 (Lion) 

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault, osx-lion, zcat, postgresql-9.0

I have a bash script as such:

```
GITUSER="mygituser"
DBUSER="mysitedbuser"
DB="mysitedb"
SITE="mysite.com"
REPO="/var/git/myproject.git" # on the server

dropdb -U $DBUSER $DB &&
echo "remote db dump (gzip)" &&
F=`ssh $GITUSER@$SITE $REPO/dumpdb-gzip.sh` &&
echo "copying remote dump to localhost" &&
scp $GITUSER@$SITE:"$F" . &&
echo "deleting remote file" &&
ssh $GITUSER@$SITE rm "$F" &&
echo "loading dump in local db" &&
createdb -U $DBUSER -E UTF8 -O $DBUSER $DB &&
psql -U postgres -c "ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO $DBUSER" $DB &&
F=`echo "$F" | sed 's/^\/tmp\///'` &&
zcat "$F" | psql -q -f - -U $DBUSER $DB >/dev/null &&
rm "$F"
```

But running in on Mac OS X (Lion) gives me this error:

```
$ ./fetch_server_db.sh
remote db dump (gzip)
copying remote dump to localhost
pg_dump_2011-10-25_09-20-50.db.gz                     100% 1017KB 254.2KB/s   00:04    
deleting remote file
loading dump in local db
ALTER SCHEMA
./fetch_server_db.sh: line 24: 25878 Broken pipe: 13         zcat "$F"
     25879 Segmentation fault: 11  | psql -q -f - -U $DBUSER $DB > /dev/null
```

I do not have such an error on Snow Leopard and this script continues to work perfectly fine on my arch linux machine. This script is failing with segmentation fault only after I upgraded to Lion.

Any idea what could be the problem? If no immediate answer is obvious, pointing me in the right direction to debug this script or to locate the source of the problem on Mac OS X Lion will do just fine! :-)

**UPDATE**

I have further isolated this problem to possibly blame it on postgresql 9.0.5. Specifically, when the line:

```
zcat "$F" | psql -q -f - -U $DBUSER $DB >/dev/null
```

is being executed (I ran the commands manually one by one in terminal), I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" error from postgresql, like this:

```
zcat "$F" | psql -q -f - -U mysitedbuser mysitedb >/dev/null
psql:-:32: ERROR:  relation "acl_dummy" already exists
psql:-:46: ERROR:  relation "acl_dummy_id_seq" already exists
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And this is the psql version I am using on my Lion:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.0.5
contains support for command-line editing

$ which psql
/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/psql

$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.0.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Any suggestions what else I can do?

Comment: Well, the error is that there 2 relations which already exist. Can't you simply delete the DB on the local host and try again?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The two errors relating the existing relations are misleading. Even if it is a blank database, I will still be getting the error:
$ zcat "$F" | psql -q -f - -U mysiteduser mysitedb >/dev/null 
Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Can you split it into 2 commands? `zcat "$F" >f.sql` and then `psql -q -f - -U mysiteduser mysitedb <f.sql` (omit the >/dev/null)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
Unfortunately, this did not work either.
I am beginning to think that it has to do with https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30090

Comment: Are you getting the same crash report (with ncurses as last action)?

Comment: Ok. I confirm that this is the same problem with the problem reported in https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30090. I recompiled my postgresql90 with a local Portfile which says

if {${configure.compiler} == "clang"} { 
    configure.compiler llvm-gcc-4.2 
} 
, portindex it and the newly compiled postgresql90 no longer gives me segmentation default 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs for Xcode 4.2 compiled postgresql packages (screws up both postgresql90 and postgresql91). (see https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30090)

The solution is to write your own Portfile in ~/ports/databases/postgresql90/Portfile by appending somewhere to line 9:

```
revision:      1
```

and appending somewhere to line 40:

```
if {${configure.compiler} == "clang"} { 
configure.compiler llvm-gcc-4.2 
}
```

Then, copy over the entire "files" subdirectory from /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/databases/postgresql90/files

Make sure that in /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf, add in

```
file:///Users/whateveryourusernameis/ports
```

before the url pointing to

```
rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar [default]
```

Then do a portindex in ~/ports or do a sudo port -v selfupdate.

And finally uninstall the previous clang compiled postgresql90 package, clean it:

```
sudo port -v uninstall postgresql90 postgresql90-server
sudo port clean postgresql90 postgresql90-server
```

and then reinstall with:

```
sudo port -v install postgresql90 postgresql90-server
```

During this reinstallation step, you should notice in the stdout that your postgresql90 packages are now being compiled by llvm-gcc-4.2.

As a general note for compilation of packages via MacPorts, we can choose which compiler to use for a specific package (port) by using the recommendations here - https://trac.macports.org/wiki/PortfileRecipes#compiler

Comment: Note, you can do this for one-off installs with something along the lines of "port install postgresql91 configure.compiler=llvm-gcc-4.2". Easier than creating your own portfile but could get clobbered with a "port upgrade outdated".

Comment: This answer is also relevant to people who have installed PostgreSQL with homebrew on OS X 10.6/10.7 with the --use-clang flag. This will cause segmentation faults when importing .sql files. The answer is, as this answer states, that clang is the problem and you must use llvm-gcc. Uninstall with homebrew and re-install without the clang flag.

Comment: @Bryson, thanks for the tip regarding homebrew.  I use homebrew on a separate mac machine belonging to my wife (macports on my own machine) so this would come in handy. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, postgres90@9.0.6 already include this amendment.

You can upgrade just by executing:

```
sudo port -v uninstall postgresql90
sudo port -v install postgresql90
```

The same happens with postgresql91